# log4c doesn't print to logfiles when starting program as a service with systemd

Tags: c++, systemd, log4c

I have an application that uses log4c for logging. It has been working well for the last few months of development. Today I wrote a systemd service file for this application to run on startup. Now log4c doesn't generate any log files. Here is my log4crc file. I even tried to specify an absolute path to the logging directory, but that didn't work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4c SYSTEM "">
<log4c>
        <config>
                <bufsize>0</bufsize>
                <debug level="2"/>
                <nocleanup>0</nocleanup>
        </config>
        <!-- root category ========================================= -->
        <category name="root" priority="debug" appender="rolling_appender"/>
        <!-- default appenders ===================================== -->
    <appender name="rolling_appender" type="rollingfile" logdir="." prefix="foo" layout="basic" rollingpolicy="rolling_policy" />
        <!-- default layouts ======================================= -->
        <layout name="basic" type="basic"/>
</log4c>
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <log4c.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "log4c tester\n");

    if (log4c_init())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to start log4c\n");
        return -1;
    }

    log4c_category_log(log4c_category_get("root"), 1, "Testing to log4c");
}
```

And here is my services file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Logging test

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/test

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have even had the test app change it's working directory prior to calling the init function. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing. The fix was extremely simple, just add a WorkingDirectory under service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Logging test

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/test
WorkingDirectory=/opt/test

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```